# Assembly x86 putting values into array with loop

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86

I wanted to put numbers in an array of length 10, but each number is 1 bigger than the last number.
It means: `myArray = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

I have tried this:

> IDEAL
>   MODEL small
>   STACK 100h
>
> DATASEG
>
> intArray db 10 dup (0)
>   index db 1
>
> CODESEG
>
> start:
>     mov ax, @DATA
>     mov ds, ax
>   loopArray:
>     mov al, [index]
>     add [intArray+index], al ; here is the problem
>     inc [index]
>     cmp [index], 11
>     jb loopArray
>   exit:
>     mov ax, 4c00h
>     int 21h
>   END start

But I can't add the index to [intArray + index], so I tried to to add it to [intArray+al], and that doesn't work either.

How can I add the index to the next array's value each time?

Comment: {add [intArray + al], al} should work, why doesn't it? Does it compile?

Comment: Why do you want to *add* the index to anything? `MOV`it there. And you'll probably have to use `BX` to index: `mov bl,[index] ; loopArray: mov [intArray + bx],bl ; inc bl : cmp bl,11 : jb loopArray` or some such.

Comment: Now my loop looks like this: ' loopArray: mov bl, [index] ; mov [intArray+bl], bl ; inc [index] ; cmp [index], 11 ; jb loopArray ' and it still doesn't work.

Comment: And yes, it does compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> myArray = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

These are the numbers that you want your array to contain. But since you initialized the *index* variable (that you will be using for both indexing and storing) as 1 (using `index db 1`) this will lead to another result.
Just setup the index with:

```
index db 0
```

There's another reason to set it up this way!
In the notation `[intArray+index]` the `index` part is meant to be an **offset** in the array. Offsets are always zero based quantities. The way you wrote your program, it will write the 10th value behind the array.

> add [intArray+index], al ; here is the problem

You're right that this is the problem. Some assemblers won't compile this, and others will just add the addresses of both these variables. Neither suits your purpose. What you need is putting the content of the *index* variable in a register and use that combination of operands.

```
    intArray db 10 dup (0)
    index    db 0
    ...
loopArray:
    movzx    bx, [index]
    mov      [intArray+bx], bl ;Give the BX-th array element the value BL
    inc      [index]
    cmp      [index], 10
    jb       loopArray
```

With this code the *index* will start at 0 and then the loop will continu for as long as the *index* is smaller than 10.

---

Of course you could write this program without using an *index* variable at all.

```
    intArray db 10 dup (0)
    ...
    xor      bx, bx            ;This make the 'index' = 0
loopArray:
    mov      [intArray+bx], bl ;Give the BX-th array element the value BL
    inc      bx
    cmp      bx, 10
    jb       loopArray
```

---

Given that the array was initially filled with zeroes, you can replace the:

```
    mov      [intArray+bx], bl ;Give the BX-th array element the value BL
```

with:

```
    add      [intArray+bx], bl ;Give the BX-th array element the value BL
```

**Do remember this can only work if the array was filled with zeroes beforehand!**

Comment: thank you, I done this yesterday, and it is the correct answer.

Comment: Very glad to have helped you!

Comment: Hello @SepRoland. How do I overwrite a small Matrix into a larger matrix?

Comment: @SepRoland what if the array is intArray db 10 dup (3 dup(0))?

Comment: @FereydoonBarikzehy  This would be equivalent to `intArray db 30 dup (0)`. The array would start with 30 zeroed elements that the code would fill with numbers from 0 to 29.